# Trying to send random string in C# Discord

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a bot in Discord. I now am working on making a random url. And to make this url, I first want to be sure the random generator works good. The random generated chars will be outputted as an array, but I want it as a string but I do not know how. I want the bot to send "LinkString" whenever I type +meme. Here is my code:

```
        {
            commands.CreateCommand("meme")
                .Do(async (e) =>
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendMessage(LinkString);
                });
        }

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {

            });
    }

    private string LinkString(int Size)
    {
       string input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, Size)
                               .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]);
        return new string(chars.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem (where and do you get an exception)? Please also remove irrelevant code

Comment: What do you mean by 'I do not know how to make it a string instead of an array'?. What specifically are you trying to turn into a string?

Comment: I changed it... Hopefully this is more clear

Comment: @EsliStavenga - still I'm failing to understand the problem.. if I copy and execute the `LinkString` method it works good

Comment: Nothing you've posted indicates that "something is an array". The only complete method in your code returns a `string`, which is what you said you want.

Comment: The bot will send that message whenever the command is executed.

Comment: @GiladGreen it gives me this error: http://imgur.com/a/XvjlC

Comment: @EsliStavenga You're missing the parenthesis and an argument for the call to `LinkString`. It should be `await e.Channel.SendMessage(LinkString(someInteger));`, assuming `SendMessage()` takes a `string`.

Comment: @sab669 I know, GEEF solved it for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give your `LinkString()` method a parameter, an `int` as you've specified. Change it to this:

```
 await e.Channel.SendMessage(LinkString(5));
```

Comment: I love you! Have a nice day

Comment: @EsliStavenga No worries, we've all done similar things at least once

Comment: @GEEFhaha true. At least thanks for helping to solve the problem. As you noticed, I am pretty new to C#

Comment: @EsliStavenga Also, consider making your `LinkString` method return like this (just for cleaner code):

`return Enumerable.Range(0, Size)
                               .Select(x => input[random.Next(0, input.Length)]).ToString();`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.